# Postgresql updatable views with non null constraints

Tags: postgresql

In my test app I have database with the following setup on a `PostgreSQL9.6` instance.

```
CREATE TABLE public.parties
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('parties_id_seq'::regclass),
  party_type_id text NOT NULL,
  fullname text NOT NULL DEFAULT ''::text,
  created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  CONSTRAINT parties_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id, party_type_id),

  (... extra sql not relevant to the question ...)
);

CREATE TABLE public.party_people
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  gender text NOT NULL DEFAULT ''::text,
  CONSTRAINT party_people_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),

  (... extra sql not relevant to the question ...)
);


CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public.people AS 
 SELECT t1.id,
    t1.party_type_id,
    t1.fullname,
    t2.gender,
    t1.created_at
   FROM parties t1
     JOIN party_people t2 ON t1.id = t2.id;


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.people_vw_update_func()
  RETURNS trigger AS
  LANGUAGE plpgsql 
  $BODY$      
  BEGIN
    IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN
      IF NEW.id IS NULL THEN
        NEW.id = NEXTVAL('parties_id_seq');
      END IF;

      INSERT INTO parties
      VALUES (NEW.id, NEW.party_type_id, NEW.fullname, NEW.created_at);

      INSERT INTO party_people
      VALUES (NEW.id, NEW.party_type_id, NEW.gender);
      RETURN NEW;
    ELSIF
       (... extra sql to deal with DELETE and UPDATE cases ...)
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
  END;
  $BODY$

 CREATE TRIGGER people_vw_update_trig
   INSTEAD OF INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
   ON people
   FOR EACH ROW
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE people_vw_update_func();
```

I'm trying to create an updatable view in postgres where I can I can manage a persons data through the `people` view instead of manually writing a query to split the data across both tables.

The issue I'm running into is I can't have a `NON NULL` constraint on the view backing tables otherwise a query like:

```
INSERT INTO people (fullname, gender)
VALUES ("James Jones", "male");
```

will fail because of the constraint on `created_at` and because `NEW.create_at` in the trigger function is obviously `NULL`

**So my question is:**
Does anyone know of a way to handle `NON NULL` constraints inside of a updatable view without resorting to something like:

```
IF NEW.created_at IS NULL THEN
    INSERT INTO parties
    VALUES (NEW.id, NEW.party_type_id, NEW.fullname);
ELSE    
    INSERT INTO parties
    VALUES (NEW.id, NEW.party_type_id, NEW.fullname, NEW.created_at);
END IF;
```

While that solution would work for a single column, if there were many more then the solution would get really messy really fast.

**EDIT**

In the end I implemented the solution recommended by *Mad Scientist*. For anyone who may stumble upon this question in the future my final solution was:

```
  ALTER TABLE people
  ALTER COLUMN created_at SET DEFAULT now()
```

That way in the view trigger all I had to do was set the values in the appropriate tables as the *people* view would take care of populating the `NEW` variable with default values where `NULL` would normally be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create default values on views, not just on tables. If you have an updatable view I would just add the default values from the underlying tables to it. The NOT NULL constraint can be enforced by the underlying table, but your INSTEAD OF triggers will see the default value if no value is supplied, instead of the problematic NULL.

The syntax for default values on views is the same as for altering default values for tables.

Answer (score 2):

You just can do:

```
IF NEW.created_at IS NULL THEN
    NEW.created_at = now() ;
END IF ;
/* Do the same for all columns requiring default values */

INSERT INTO 
       parties 
       (id,     party_type_id,     fullname,     created_at)
VALUES 
       (NEW.id, NEW.party_type_id, NEW.fullname, NEW.created_at);
```

or also

```
INSERT INTO 
       parties 
       (id,     party_type_id,     fullname,     created_at)
VALUES 
       (NEW.id, NEW.party_type_id, NEW.fullname, coalesce(NEW.created_at, now()));
```

Check the [documentation on Coalesce](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL).

Comment: +1 for recommending the coalesce function. It's pretty much the exact solution I was looking for, though ultimately I went with Mad Scientists answer because I think putting default values on the view is better for my purposes.